# Fetch all primary keys with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to fetch all primary keys from a table, but I don't want to fetch any of the other fields from the db. What I've found so far is recommendations to use `Repo.all` and `Map.take` but that clearly fetches too much from the database.

How do I fetch a single field from all entries in an ecto schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Ecto.Query.select/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#select/3) is your friend.

```elixir
from u in User, select: u.id
```

To retrieve several fields, use

```elixir
from u in User, select: {u.id, u.name}
```

Comment: `module.__schema__(:primary_key)` can also be useful :)

Comment: I think that this additional tuple around single value may be irritating.

Comment: @Hauleth I gave it a thought and decided that it shows the extensibility to return 2+ fields. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin why not have two code snippets? one answering the exact question and one suggesting a very likely extension?

Comment: @FilipHaglund please feel free to edit my answer as you find it more appropriate.